# Nil HydroCarbon in the exaust

Tags: engine, exhaust

If hydrocarbons (HC) are nil and Carbon Monoxide (CO) is 0.33% and Carbon Dioxide (CO2) is 14%

Why does the HC show up as nil?

Is there a problem with having no HC readings?

Comment: Is this at the tail pipe or before a convertor? I'd think that 0 hydrocarbons in the exhaust gases would be a good thing?

Comment: I'd also like to know the NOx levels, and the free O2 levels.  On a 3-way catalyzed exhaust, HC=0 is, as Ben indicates, a common and good thing.